# How to ignore these files when I get error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge - Git

Tags: git

`git pull origin master` gives me the following messages:

```
Updating da4fe55..2fda2d1
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        app/Http/Controllers/AppointmentsController.php
        resources/assets/js/userschedule.js
        resources/views/home.blade.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Read other stackoverflow questions/answers and tried the commands below, nothing worked (don't understand why they didn't help):

```
git checkout origin/master -f
git checkout master -f
git stash (and git pull after)
git reset HEAD --hard
git clean -fd
```

Isn't there a way to completely ignore these files? Not sure what to try next.

This is a project I cloned from bitbucket, and I didn't change any of those local files. The project in bitbucket was updated so I was looking to update my local files using a `git pull`.

After testing git add .

git status

```
# Changes to be committed:
#
#       modified:   public/js/userschedule.js
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified:      app/Http/Controllers/AppointmentsController.php
#       both modified:      resources/assets/js/userschedule.js
#       both modified:      resources/views/home.blade.php
```

Comment: git tells you the two options you have - either commit these files or stash them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, nothing should be changed, so it's probably a new line issue. This should resolve it:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

It will reset your local branch and makes its equal to the master branch on origin. All local changes (even committed) will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

This error is normal to happen. If someone else edited and pushed, you have to merge theirs commit. So, you can do two things:

**Merge commits**

Normally, you want to add your changes to the repository. So, you commit your changes, and merge:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Foo commit"
git pull origin master
```

Now, you just have to merge it (if there are conflicts)

**Ignore your changes**

If you don't want to keep your changes, just remove it, and pull:

```
git checkout .
git pull origin master
```

*Be careful: With this, you will lose what you changed at the code!*

Comment: Thanks what I don't understand, I never changed this code. It was originally cloned from the remote repo. Now I want to update my local files with the remote repo, but I keep getting the error.

Comment: After `git status` and `git diff`, does it print any change?

Comment: I tried `git checkout .` and `git pull`, and I get the same error.

Comment: `git add .` gave `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in .bowerrc.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.`

Comment: When you say: `you want to add your changes to the repository` . Are you talking about the remote repo? I don't want to overwrite what's in my remote repo. And like I said, there were no changes in my local repo.

Comment: Ok. I've just read your `git status`. The `both modified` means that you already committed and pulled (that is why `git checkout . ; git pull` is not working). I would like to understand what you want to do. Do you want to ignore all your code and pull? Do you want to push your code to another repository?

Comment: So I think you should follow Julian answer. He got your problem faster than me :).

Comment: Thanks for your help Rafael!